# Azure Load balancer probe and traffic on different interface - possbile?

Tags: azure, azure-load-balancer

I have a VM with 2 network interfaces.
As per my requirement, when this VM is placed behind azure load balancer, I want health probes to reach Interface-1 and actual traffic to reach interface-2 is it possible ?
(FYI.. Due to some reason I don't want to use my interface-2 to answer health probes)

Comment: probably not, as probe is using same ip address\nic as the actual rule, you can only configure probe port (maybe path as well, dont remember right now)

Answer (score 0):

When you have 2 Interface generally you don't have communication between 2 NICs. So in the guest OS level, you need to add a default route to allow traffic between two NICs. Once that is done, traffic to the Interface 1 will be forwarded to the Interface 2 and it will work.

I will give you the reference to add default route.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/virtual-machines/windows/multiple-nics#configure-guest-os-for-multiple-nics